# Build error -> ##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s\**\*.sln'

Tags: build, azure-devops

**YAMAL config file:**

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

**Error:**

##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s***.sln'.

**RAW log:**

2020-06-26T13:39:42.7115236Z ##[section]Starting: VSBuild
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7374773Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7375115Z Task         : Visual Studio build
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7375427Z Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7375688Z Version      : 1.166.2
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7375904Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7376240Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build
2020-06-26T13:39:42.7376608Z ==============================================================================
2020-06-26T13:39:46.1317137Z ##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s***.sln'.
2020-06-26T13:39:46.1880482Z ##[section]Finishing: VSBuild

Comment: The error message is clear: `Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s***.sln'.`. Have you confirmed that there is a file that matches that pattern?

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this file path. How do we check? Its in the cloud not local.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agree with Daniel, the error message `Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s***.sln'` clearly states that the cause of this error is that the .sln file is not found in the `s` folder.

You need to check whether your `.sln` file is pushed to the version control. You can search this in source repo of azure devops.

Comment: Thanks very much to Hugh Lin and Daniel Mann, I'm new of this so learning by doing some question might be obvous at your experienced eyes, but in my case is a learning curve

Cheers!

Comment: What are we supposed to do with this file path. How do we check? Its in the cloud not local

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my yaml pipelines,
`##[error]Solution not found using search pattern 'D:\a\1\s\**\*.sln'`

So I made it as my code & the yaml file are in same branch. Now it will work, I hope it will help you.